# Form Inheritance in Visual Studios designer implementations

Tags: vb.net, forms, inheritance, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-2003

I'm in the process of moving a project from Visual Studio 2003 to 2005 and have just seen the

> The event Click is read-only and cannot be changed

when using inherited forms regardless of the Modifier on the Base Forms Controls will make all the Controls from the Base Readonly in the designer (Though in 2003 it didn't work this way).

I found this post mentioning that this functionality has been temporarily" disabled
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/c25cec28-67a5-4e30-bb2d-9f8dbd41eb3a

Can anyone confirm whether this feature is used anymore? Or how to program around it to be able to use the Base Control Events and still have a designer?

This is one way I've found but quite painful when it used to do the plumbing for you. Even just hiding one of the controls you have manually do now.

```
Public Class BFormChild

    Friend Overrides Sub cmdApply_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.cmdApply_Click(sender, e)
    End Sub
    Friend Overrides Sub cmdCancel_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.cmdCancel_Click(sender, e)
    End Sub
    Friend Overrides Sub cmdOk_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.cmdOk_Click(sender, e)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base classes that generate events require the standard event generation pattern.  That must be done in code, the designer cannot auto-generate it.  It never will.

```
Public Class BFormBase
  Public Event ApplyClicked As EventHandler

  Protected Overridable Sub OnApplyClicked(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    '--- Possible default implementation here
    '...
    RaiseEvent ApplyClicked(Me, e)
  End Sub

  Private Sub cmdApply_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdApply.Click
    OnApplyClicked(e)
  End Sub
```

Comment: oh derr.. this is probably why they took it out.. 

in VS 2003 you could directly link to the Control in the base class (which is why I'm asking) and Run the event directly in the child form & the designer did auto generate the code.
This way does make more sense to keep it in line with the Design Structures of .net.  Thanks